# RecyclerView shows only one item even if there are many

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I fetch data from database and put it to RecyclerView. My database arrives 4 items I see it with log debug then I send it to my adapter. However I see only first item on my screen.
my adapter **ListArticleAdapter**

```
package uz.sherdevs.alishernavoiy.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

import uz.sherdevs.alishernavoiy.R;
import uz.sherdevs.alishernavoiy.model.Article;

public class ListArticleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListArticleAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Article> articleList;

    public ListArticleAdapter(Context context, List<Article> articleList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.articleList = articleList;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tv_title.setText(articleList.get(position).getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //        Log.d("list", "" + articleList.size());
        return articleList.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tv_title;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.article_title);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
package uz.sherdevs.alishernavoiy;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.List;
import uz.sherdevs.alishernavoiy.adapter.ListArticleAdapter;
import uz.sherdevs.alishernavoiy.database.SQLiteDBHelper;
import uz.sherdevs.alishernavoiy.model.Article;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView articleRecyclerView;
    private ListArticleAdapter adapter;
    private List<Article> articleList;
    private SQLiteDBHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        articleRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.articles_recyclerview);
        dbHelper = new SQLiteDBHelper(this);

        articleList = dbHelper.getArticles();

//        for (Article article : articleList) {
//            Log.d("list", article.getTitle());
//        }

        articleRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapter = new ListArticleAdapter(this, articleList);

//        Log.d("list", articleList.toString());
        articleRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        articleRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background_icon"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/background_regtangle_green"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/circle_background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="Dostonlar"
        android:textColor="#FFDF6A"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/circle_background"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/circle_background"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/circle_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/circle_background"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3"
        android:fontFamily="@font/myfont"
        />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/articles_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize">
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**item_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardview1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.15"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.23"
            app:cardElevation="20dp"
            >

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/article_title"
                    android:textSize="45sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.6"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I got 4 Objects from my database with command

```
articleList = dbHelper.getArticles();
```

However I see only first one on the screen.
Moreover as you see I loged in my adapter

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //        Log.d("list", "" + articleList.size());
        return articleList.size();
    }
```

That size also shows 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `item_list.xml`, change `android:layout_height="match_parent"` with `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: if I changed android:layout_height="match_parent" to android:layout_height="wrap_content" in ConstraintLayout and LinearLayout nothing shows on the screen

Comment: Because TextView height is `0dp`. Put `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in every  views of `item_list.xml`